# laravel can resource back string not array

Tags: laravel, resources

I have a resource which calls another resource to format dimensions. Simply divison by 10.

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'height' => new DimensionFormatResource($this->height),
    ];
}
```

And dimension resource like

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    $format = '10';
    return $this->resource/$format;

}
```

And i get response in API like

```
        "height": [
            47.2
        ],
```

How can i get a string instead like

```
        "height": 47.2,
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'height' => $this->height/10,
    ];
}
```

This would solve the issue. I am not sure why do you need another function to convert to an array.

Comment: I want to use this resource to format not only height but other dimensions too. And i want to get back that in without []. I tried to use withoutWrapping() but it's not work for me maybe im doing smth wrong

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `toArray` function with `$request` param after calling the resource instance, it'll return whatever you've set as the array.

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
            'height' => new DimensionFormatResource($this->height)->toArray($request),
    ];
}
```